# Mozart (Emacs) shotrtcuts on mac

Tags: macos, emacs, mozart

I'm learning Oz language. Im using Mozart for this and learning from this tutorial: http://mozart.github.io/mozart-v1/doc-1.4.0/tutorial/\
I'm a total beginner on it.
There is a lot of shortcuts in this tutorial and I just can't find them on my keyboard...
I'm using Mac OS X.

I figured what means 
C-. C-l (ctrl + . and the next ctrl + l)

but for example I can't figure out what means M-C-x ???
Its driving me crazy ;(

Do you know any useful resources that I can find more info about this style of writing shortcuts?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/User-Input.html

Comment: If you want to read Emacs documentation, start with the beginning of the Emacs manual, which explains the conventions.

Comment: `M` is pronounced "Meta" and  is either the option/alt key or the command key – different "editions" of Emacs on os x configure the keys differently.  And there's a tutorial, as well as a complete manual, available in the "Help" menu.

Answer (score 0):

As comments suggested, start with Emacs Tutorial

Afterwards:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-key` <kbd>RET</kbd> KEY <kbd>RET</kbd> will show you the real command-name.

Instead of typing the key, all commands are accessible via

<kbd>M-x</kbd> COMMAND <kbd>RET</kbd>

Commonly command-names are easier to memorize - and it's a mistake of tutorials focusing on keys.

Once you called a command by its name, a message will display the key afterwards - just to remind of that easier way to invoke, once got used to it.

Comment: I think OP is asking what `M-` *means*, so telling them to type `M-x` might not be of much help.